# jQuery slideDown example with some constraints

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, slidetoggle

I want to find the div-container with the class ".div1", which contains a radio button with the value 100 and this container should slideDown().

Following command does not work:

```
$('.div1 :input[value="100"]').slideDown();
```

the HTML Structure looks:

```
<div class="div1">
    <span>some text div1</span>
    <span>
        <input class="ca" type="radio" name="hello" val="100">
        <input class="ca" type="radio" name="hello" val="200">    
    </span>
</div>

<div class ="div2">
    <span>some text div2</span>
    <span>
        <input type="radio" name="hi" val="300" class="cb">
        <input type="radio" name="hi" val="400" class="cb">
    </span>
</div>
```

and that's the css:

```
.div1,.div2 {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your used selector is `.div1 :input[value="100"]`. It selected the `input` that `value=100` not the `.div1` you want to slide it down.

So, You need to move up the `.div1` (parent) to slide it down.

```
$(':input[val="100"]').parents('.div1').slideDown();
```

Comment: Be aware that you used "val" instead of "value", so the right selector is $('input[val="100"]')

Comment: But as @billyonecan pointed out, there is not "val" attribute and your markup is not valid. If you really want to have custom attributes, use "data-*" notation (http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to use `value="x"` in your markup, not `val="x"`, otherwise the attribute selector won't match anything, and your markup will be invalid.

`<input class="ca" type="radio" name="hello" value="100" />`